# I've to design a web application with 1000 of forms

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've to design a web application with 1000 of forms. The application needs to store all forms and forms data in database and all forms should be manageable from admin panel. Admin should be able to manage all forms and also manage how preview or form with some content display after form submit. what the right approach for this.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I need a car with a blue window.

Comment: use template for form creation, have form components stored in flexible data-structure like XML. Parse, alter, create and load them as and when need. BTW, I liked @Pabuc comment. +1.

Comment: Agreed with @Nishant, the key here is to use a loooot of templates, altough determining the templates may not be an easy task...

Comment: Thanks for answer.Each form has different fields and its preview(its a html page with form field and varies according to form) should be available in user control panel for download in different format.Can you please suggest a template system that is used.

Comment: Make a `FormGenerator` class, that according to an xml document generates the form for you. Store those xml documents somewhere so that a management console can change them. Creating more xml documents is relatively cheap and the formgenerator will do the rest.

Comment: Why do you guys not post your comments as answers? For example, @Bazzz's comment looks like a decent answer that can get an upvote.

Comment: @Bazzz +1, good solution but why to use xml, why not save the forms meta-data in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 on @Bazzz. Maybe use the Form-component of Zend Framework to read XML-configurations and render the forms. I think Zend Forms is usually a bit too much for a few forms, but if you are looking into 1000 is worth a look.

A bit outdated but the concept is the same...
http://blog.snakehit.be/2008/03/09/zend_form-with-xml-tutorial/